# What does "дл. тонны" mean?

Tags: прилагательные, существительные, терминология, сокращения

From [Russian Wikipedia on the Fletcher-Class Destroyers](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%86%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0_%C2%AB%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%C2%BB), it says,

> Двигательная установка компоновочно повторяла тип «Гливз» — была высокотемпературной установкой среднего (43 Атм.) давления, которая теоретически обеспечивала на 20-30 % большую эффективность, чем современные конструкции подавляющего большинства иностранных эсминцев. Платой за это была большая масса энергетической установки, которая составляла 787—822 дл. тонны. Запас топлива составлял 491 дл.

So at the end it speaks of "дл. тонны" and "дл". What does the dl mean? Google translate doesn't know what it is. I tried general google search but got nothing either.

I suspect it is some type of imperial ton, such as the long ton or short ton. However, I tried both of those on wikipedia and looked at the Russian version, but did not see "дл." abbreviation mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the direct translation of [long ton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_ton). This translation variant even [exists in Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Comment: The wikipedia page never uses the abbreviation "дл." anywhere. I would feel more comfortable with a definitive source. However, after more searching i did find https://www.abbreviations.com/term/528167 which says it stands for "длина", which means "length". So i think you are right but i wish there was some direct authoritative source for it.

Comment: @DrZ214 дл. тонны = длинных тонны.

Comment: https://bbf.ru/converter/283/

Comment: " looked at the Russian version, but did not see "дл." abbreviation mentioned anywhere." - i suppose, the "Russian version" just doesn't exist, we use metric system and SI; and for archaic Russian system here is nothing equal too... use convertor. Длинная тонна ≈ массе 1 м³ морской воды ≈ 1015 — 1020 кг.   https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Английская_тонна (длинная тонна) - just a literally translation.

Comment: Although it won't help in this particular case, the website http://sokr.ru/ is good for looking up acronyms and abbreviations.